# Replacing empty fields in delimited text file with dummy value

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I am working on a project that takes a delimited set of data of the form:

```
field1~field2~field3~.....~fieldn
```

Having empty fields is a possibility, so

```
field1~~~field4~~field6
```

is perfectly acceptable.

This file gets translated using an inhouse translator program that leaves a little to be desired.  Specifically, it doesn't deal with empty fields well.  My solution was to stick some dummy value in there, like a space or an @ sign.  I've tried:

```
sed -r 's/~/~ ~/g'
```

and

```
awk '{gsub(/\~\~/,"~ ~")}; 1' file > file.SPACE
```

but both of these fall short in replacing MULTIPLE fields.  So if I input

```
field1~field2~~~field3
```

it'll output:

```
field1~field2~ ~~field3
```

I'd like to just script this if I could, as I can't change the code of the translator.  I can change the code in the program that creates the delimited file, but I'd rather not.  Is there some workaround, or is coming up with an expression for this just one of the inherent limitations in a regular language?

**EDIT:** Wow thanks for the quick response everyone,  all your solutions worked so I upvoted all of them.  I think I'm going to accept Janito's because of the explanation.

Also why the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
sed -e ':a;s/~~/~ ~/;ta'
```

This creates a label "a" with the ":" command, then replaces one occurrance of `~~` with `~ ~`, and then uses the "t" test command to jump back to the "a" label if the previous substitute command succeeded.

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{for( i=0; i<=NF; i++ ) if( $i ~ /^$/ ) $i = " " } 1' FS='~' OFS='~' input
```

or:

```
awk '/^$/{ $0 = " " } 1' ORS='~' RS='~' input
```

or:

```
awk '{ while( gsub( "~~", "~ ~" )); }1' input
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e ':loop' -e 's/~~/~ ~/g' -e 't loop' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Perl

```
perl -pe 's/~(?=~)/~ /g'
```

*...which says replace each `"~"` followed by `"~"` with `"~ "`*

---

To store result(s) to `file.SPACE`  use

```
perl -pe 's/~(?=~)/~ /g' file >file.SPACE
```