# replace NULL token in Hive CLI output

Tags: perl, hive, command-line-interface

I am trying to deliver the output of Hive CLI to my (closed source) application, and want to replace all "NULL" tokens with empty string. This is because Hive returns NULL even for numeric fields which the application raises exceptions for. I thought this should be a simple sed, or perl regex, but cant solve the problem so far.

Here's an example of the data record -

```
NULL<TAB>NULL<TAB>NULL<TAB>NULL<TAB>NULL<TAB>NULL<TAB>NULL<TAB>NULL<TAB>2015-02-08
```

The perl code I tried is

```
my %replace = (
    "\tNULL\t" => "b",
    "^NULL\t"  => "a",
    "\tNULL\$" => "c"
);

my $regex = join "|", keys %replace;
#$regex = qr/$regex/;

my $filename = hout;
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  chomp $row;
  $row =~ s/($regex)/$replace{$1}/g;
  print "$row\n";
}
```

This is the output I get -

```
NULLbNULLbNULLbNULL<TAB>2015-02-08
```

In other words, in a stream of 'fields' delimited by a 'character', I want to replace any field that is equal to the string "NULL" with an empty string, so the delimiters surrounding the field (or start of line + delimiter, or delimiter + end of line) become adjacent.

Any guidance would be much appreciated! Thanks!

P.S. I dont need a perl solution per se; just any terse solution would be awesome (I tried sed as well with similar results)

Comment: The output gets me thinking if the regex replacement applies the patterns iteratively and therefore sees the argument string change from preceding replacements.

Comment: I think your problem will be because `\tNULL\t` 'eats' 2 tabs. What are you _trying_ to extract from that line? Have you considered instead of what you're doing, using `split ( /\t/ )`; as an option?

Comment: @Sobrique, thanks I tried this 

**New code**
`my %replace = (
    "\tNULL\t" => "\t\t",
    "^NULL\t"  => "\t",
    "\tNULL\$" => "\t"
);`

New Output
`NULL<TAB>NULL<TAB>NULL<TAB>NULL<TAB>2015-02-08`

Comment: Thanks @Sobrique. I changed the 'b', 'a' and 'c' back to the same number as <TAB> characters as in the search regex, but the output is similar. I changed them to a, b, c so I could tell which one of the regexes were being processed. Also, good point about the 'split'. My only concern is that loses the sense of the NULL token i.e. if the tab is between a quoted string, it would split that out too - technically though I could reconstruct it by examining the array - so yeah, that might work. So nothing terse ha?

Comment: The output I am looking to achieve is

`<TAB><TAB><TAB><TAB><TAB><TAB><TAB><TAB>2015-02-08`

Basically, I want to remove all **NULL tokens**

Comment: So couldn't you just: `s/NULL//g;` or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Yeah, just replacing NULL with empty string misses the sense of the **token NULL **. meaning that will remove NULL even when its part of a **"field"**

like so - 

`CONTRACT NULLIFIED<TAB>NULL<TAB>`

with the replace you shared would return

`CONTRACT <TAB><TAB>`

when I want

`CONTRACT NULLIFIED<TAB><TAB>`

Does that make sense?

Comment: Nobody got nothing??

Comment: This looks like its working - I would appreciate if someone sees a reason why this would not work, sharing why - Thanks in advance!

`sed -e ":a;s/\tNULL\t/\t*\t/;ta" -e "s/^NULL\t/*\t/g"   -e "s/\tNULL$/\t*/g" hout`

Comment: If that does, credit's due to [Janito Vaqueiro Ferreira Filho](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12733083/2889133)

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem here is that your patterns overlap. You have a delimiter either side of your 'NULL' which you then modify and move on.

So something like this:

```
my $string = "NULL\tNULL\tNULL\tsome_value\tNULL\n";
print $string;

$string =~ s/(\A|\t)NULL(\t|\Z)/$1$2/g;
print $string;
$string =~ s/(\A|\t)NULL(\t|\Z)/$1$2/g;
print $string;
```

You need two passes to process it, because the pattern 'grabs' too much for the next iteration to match. 
So with reference to: [Matching two overlapping patterns with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259677/matching-two-overlapping-patterns-with-perl)

What you probably need is:

```
$string =~ s/(\A|\t)NULL(?=(\t|\Z))/$1/g;
```

You can use the same model if you're wanting to apply it to separate patterns.

Comment: ah - so like i thought, the regex utility is able to see the argument string 'evolve' as its applying the replace. Thanks I will give your perl regex a try - the sed I noted above seems to be working, but is slowing things down a lot, hopefully, the perl solution is at least as accuracte, and much faster!

Comment: Not exactly - regex works through the string, and it doesn't so much 'evolve' as know it's 'already seen that bit'. So if it's already matched against a tab, it'll ignore it again.

Answer (score 0):

I do this a lot creating output files from hive cli, it may be "simple" but I just pipe my output though this sed string:

hive -f test.hql | sed 's/NULL//g' > test.out

Works fine for me.